# Debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints inside JQuery event handler functions (Chrome)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, debugging, breakpoints, javascript-debugger

I noticed that breakpoints inside JQuery event handler functions are not triggered.
If I put an alert or a `debugger;` it works fine.

I cannot understand if this is a Chrome known issue or if this could be related to my specific configuration. I work on windows 7 and Google Chrome is updated.

Comment: I've set breakpoints inside jQuery event handlers and they worked fine.

Comment: Does it still fail if you disable all Chrome extensions? (Plug: there's an extension called "Disable Extensions Temporarily" that allows you to enable and disable all extensions with one click.)

Comment: @barmar it seems that disabling chrome extensions solves the problem. Thank you

Comment: You should try to figure out which extension is conflicting with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @barmar says in his comment, if I disable all Chrome extensions, breakpoints works fine.